# unable to perform other tasks in case HP QTP script is executing?

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

I want to continue my work while HP UFT is executing the script but it is unable to do,while QTP/UFT test scripts are executing i'm unable to perform any other works on laptop,please provide solution how to do.

Comment: Execute the script on another PC.

Answer (score 0):

Start > HP > hp product > silent test runner
more details :-
 http://uft-help.saas.hpe.com/en/14.00/UFT_Help/Content/User_Guide/Silent_Test_Runner_Conceptual.htm